# Creating a new column by applying conditions on the columns selected based on regular expression(as number of columns are dynamic)

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with columns as first ,col1,col2,col3,row1
import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], 'col1': ['yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'no'], 'col2': ['yes', 'yes', 'no', 'no' ,'yes', 'yes' ,'no', 'no'], 'col3': ['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no','yes', 'no','yes', 'no'], 'row1':['4','5','7','3','7','3','79','8']})
```

first col1 col2 col3 row1
1  yes  yes  yes    4
2  yes  yes   no    5
3  yes   no  yes    7
4  yes   no   no    3
5   no  yes  yes    7
6   no  yes   no    3
7   no   no  yes   79
8   no   no   no    8

i want to apply conditions as below and create a new column as new_one

```
df.loc[((df['col1']=='no') & (df['col2']=='no') & (df['col3'] == 'no')),'new_one'] = 'no'
df.loc[~((df['col1']=='no') & (df['col2']=='no') & (df['col3'] == 'no')),'new_one'] = 'yes`
```

**Problem:** number of columns in the dataframe is dynamic and it is not constant as 3 in the above data frame but it matches with a pattern , here it is 'col*'

i want to select columns based up on the pattern(here col*) and apply the condition ('== 'no'') to each column and '&' them, and create a new column as new_one

i implemented the below code but not working

```
col_list=[]
for name in df.columns:
    if(re.search("col",name))
        col_list.append(name)
count=0
cond=''
for col in col_list:
   if(count==0):
      cond+="(df[\'"+col+"\'] == 'no')"
   else:
      cond+="&(df[\'"+col+"\'] == 'no')"
   count=count+1

df.loc[cond,'new_one'] = 'no'
df.loc[~cond,'new_one'] = 'no'
```

**problem:** cond is a str , i dont know how to use that as condition as df.loc expects cond to be series.i tried eval as well but no luck.please let me know any solution to this?

```
first col1 col2 col3 row1 new_one
1  yes  yes  yes    4     yes
2  yes  yes   no    5     yes
3  yes   no  yes    7     yes
4  yes   no   no    3     yes
5   no  yes  yes    7     yes
6   no  yes   no    3     yes
7   no   no  yes   79     yes
8   no   no   no    8      no
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html)/[`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df.loc[df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].eq('no').all(axis=1), 'new_one'] = 'no'
df.loc[df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].ne('no').any(axis=1), 'new_one'] = 'yes'
```

Or, for both yes/no in a single command, [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new_one'] = np.where(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].eq('no').all(axis=1),
                         'no', 'yes')
```

Output:

```
  first col1 col2 col3 row1 new_one
0     1  yes  yes  yes    4     yes
1     2  yes  yes   no    5     yes
2     3  yes   no  yes    7     yes
3     4  yes   no   no    3     yes
4     5   no  yes  yes    7     yes
5     6   no  yes   no    3     yes
6     7   no   no  yes   79     yes
7     8   no   no   no    8      no
```

##### dynamic number of columns:

```
mask = df.filter(like='col').eq('no').all(axis=1)

df['new_one'] = np.where(mask, 'no', 'yes')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer , problem is number of columns matches with pattern col* and it is dynamic

Comment: @sandeepunna then `df.filter(like='col').eq('no').all(axis=1)`

Comment: @mozway Despite the question problem, your answer gave me a good tutorial, and I learned something about Pandas DataFrame manipulation. This problem sounds to me like *logic* `XOR/XNOR` applications possibly over _multiple_ columns within DataFrame [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043739/logical-operation-on-two-columns-of-a-dataframe), [ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69052548/xor-operator-in-pandas-query), [ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70264768/10452700) but I'm not sure if it can be used for _dynamic number of columns_ scenario.

Comment: @Mario yes you can use `np.logical_and.reduce(df.filter(like='col').eq('no'), axis=1)` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using **lambda** here you counting the number of time 'no' occurrence.

```
df['new'] = df[['col1','col2','col3']].T.apply(lambda r: 'no' if list(r).count('no')==3 else 'yes')
```